# Atom editor & Processing - 'processing-java' not recognised

Tags: processing, atom-editor

I am trying to use [bleikamp's Processing package](https://github.com/bleikamp/processing) to run Processing sketches from the Atom editor. The package has installed correctly, but running a sketch produces the below error:

> 'processing-java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I have added the path to my Processing directory to the `PATH` environment variable. Can anyone suggest why this is not working?

Comment: Does running `processing-java` in the Command Prompt output the same error?

Comment: @CodeMacabre Yes

Comment: Can you try running `processing-java.exe` using your entire processing directory path in the Command Prompt? For example, for me: `"c:\program files\processing\processing-java.exe"`

Comment: @CodeMacabre This executed fine

Comment: Hmm, it sounds like the path to your Processing directory is incorrectly listed in your `PATH`. Can you double-check the Processing path you used in the command above is exactly the same as listed in your `PATH`?

Comment: @CodeMacabre It's definitely correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly to do with your `PATH`. As you've checked the Processing path is correct, there may be  something preventing it from being recognised (there are some known issues, such as the `PATH` variable being too long or having invalid characters).

### Solution 1:

Try using [FixPath](http://www.westmesatech.com/cmdprompt.html#6) to fix some of the more common problems.

### Solution 2:

Try modifying the `processing` package itself to point directly to `processing-java.exe` (it points to the `PATH` variable by default).

- In Atom's `Settings > Packages`, select the `processing` package and click on 'View Code'.
- Make a backup of `\lib\processing.coffee` to be safe.
- In `\lib\processing.coffee`, search for the following code (probably near the top):

  ```
  module.exports = Processing =
    config:
      'processing-executable':
        type:"string",
        default:"processing-java"
  ```
- Modify the value of `default` to point to the exact Processing directory and `processing-java.exe`, for example:

  ```
  module.exports = Processing =
    config:
      'processing-executable':
        type:"string",
        default:"c:\\program files\\processing\\processing-java.exe"
  ```

As Chris rightly points out in the comments below, backslash `\` is an escape character in JavaScript and CoffeeScript, so itself needs to be escaped in the file path (hence the double-backslashes `\\`).

Comment: The `PATH` variable is very long, but unfortunately I can't download the FixPath tool due to internet restrictions. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Chris I've added an alternative solution. I haven't tried it myself, but it should work. If you decide to switch packages from `processing` to `script`, let me know and I'll update my answer with `script`-specific instructions.

Comment: Thank you - that worked. Thanks for your effort, much appreciated! One thing I would add to your solution in case anyone else uses this, is that you need to escape the backslashes in the path: `default:"c:\\program files\\processing\\processing-java.exe"`

Answer (score 2):

You have to install `processing-java` command line tool.

In processing, go to `Tools` `->` `Install "processing-java"`

Comment: `Install "processing-java"` is not an option under `Tools`. To clarify, I am using Windows.